# Chrome browsert throws white authentication box after hitting the URL

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, authentication, automation, browser-automation

I am writing UI automation test cases in selenium, java framework.  I am able to ran all the test case without any issue until there was no authentication implemented. After the implementation of authentication, they introduced username and password and login button. Now I am not able to ran any UI automation test in chrome browser, I am getting a white authentication box saying to server xxxx requires the username and password when I hit the URL through automation script. it prevent the selenium script to click any where on webpage.

At the same time I am able to work fine manually in chrome browser. I can able to click on login icon.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for webdriver to work you have to pass username and password in the authentication box you can do it like below

Way 1 : Work with Selenium Alert

```
Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();   
alt.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(uid, pwd));
```

Way 2 : pass user name and password in the url directly

```
driver.get("http://username:password@yoururl.com");
```

Way 3 : use robot class of java

```
 Robot rb = new Robot();

     //Enter user name by ctrl-v
     StringSelection username = new StringSelection("username");
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

     //tab to password entry field
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     Thread.sleep(2000);

     //Enter password by ctrl-v
     StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("password");
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

     //press enter
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi Rajanish, Thing is that I want to click on login button and provide the username and password explicitly but when I navigation to URL in chrome it gives me authentication box and prevent automation script to click any where. when I am navigate to this url manually in chrome it wont give me authentication block but it give only when automation script runs

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the authentication box

Comment: @VarunRaje, I would bet that if you clear your Chrome browser cache, you will be prompted for authentication when you then navigate to the URL manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add user and password in the base url link like: http://user:password@your_domain  ?